# Could LDPC function change length of message? and how?

Tags: matlab, forwarderrorcorrection

This is MATLAB code about `LDPC` (Low Density Parity Check). Could I change the length of `data`? and how?

```
ldpcEncoder = comm.LDPCEncoder;
data = logical(randi([0 1],32400,1));
% Transmit and receive LDPC coded signal data
    encData = ldpcEncoder(data);
```

I try to change the length of `data`, but MATLAB always warns that "Input must be a column vector of length `K`, the message length." Is this length of `data` is fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The input of the LDPC codes should be always of length `K`, otherwise, the parity matrix would change and the code would be different. When you create an `LDPCEncoder` object in MATLAB, you are defining the `K` and `N` lengths, so the input data can't change.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could I ask another question? Could I generate a paritycheck matrix and use comm.LDPCEncoder to encode data?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can create your comm.LDPCEncoder with certain parity check matrix in the following way:

    comm.LDPCEncoder(ParityCheckMatrix);

For example, if you want to generate a DVB-S2 encoder for a code rate of 1/2, the code will be:

    p = dvbs2ldpc(1/2);
    enc = comm.LDPCEncoder(p);

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can create your comm.LDPCEncoder with certain parity check matrix in the following way:

```
comm.LDPCEncoder(ParityCheckMatrix)
```

For example, if you want to generate a DVB-S2 encoder for a code rate of 1/2, the code will be:

```
p = dvbs2ldpc(1/2);
enc = comm.LDPCEncoder(p);
```